# Is there anything like DelayedJob, but not use Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm building a web site with Rails, which will do something in the background. I don't want to use DelayedJob, because it needs a database.

What I wan't to do is simple: get some data from another site, save the response in the memory, and keep it for 10 minutes.

Is there any tools can do this?

Comment: FWIW, DelayedJob has pluggable backends. You could go through the trouble of writing a flat file backend. (I couldn't find an existing one.) The code to support ActiveRecord is really only 80ish lines: http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/backend/active_record.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use resque http://github.com/defunkt/resque. It uses a redis backed data store rather than the database.

Answer (score 1):

You might want also want to try [whenever](http://github.com/javan/whenever). It's basically a ruby script that writes the scheduled job to cron.

Comment: thank you. Whenever seems very good, I will try it somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rake task in background to do this. Run it as a cron job or a daemon to perform tasks in the background.

Comment: you can store the results in memcached or some flat file....whatever way you want. Memcached would be better since it has a time to expiry.

Comment: If you want to run the rake task from the app this might help http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background

Comment: I tried Memcached, but found it need at least 48M, this is too expensive for my poor VPS(240M memory), and I decide to use Resque. Thanks for your information~